# How do I use EntityFramework generated DbSet with DataContext on a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-6

### Question

I have an EntityFramework generated DbSet to which I bind from a Grid.DataContext as

```
myEntities = new MyEntities();
grMain.DataContext = myEntities.GalleryLists.ToList();
```

And all is grand and dandy, but List is not an observable collection. I actually (probably) want to do this:

```
grMain.DataContext = myEntities.GalleryLists.Local; //myEntities.GalleryLists //???;
```

But that latter option, which I want to work very much, gives me empty ListBoxes in this Grid, while the former one works perfectly. So what am I doing wrong?

### More details

The Grid is defined with ListBoxes in the following way (set up for binding to the List of Gallery):

```
<Grid Name="grMain">
   <!-- Column definitions and such -->
    <ListBox Name="lbxLists" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GalleryName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Name="lbxItems" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lbxLists, Path=SelectedItem.GalleryItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=GalleryItemPath}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Entity Framework generated objects looks like this:

```
public partial class TiresiasEntities : DbContext
{
    public TiresiasEntities()
        : base("name=TiresiasEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<GalleryItem> GalleryItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GalleryList> GalleryLists { get; set; }
}
public partial class Gallery
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public GalleryList()
    {
        this.GalleryItems = new HashSet<GalleryItem>();
    }

    public int GalleryID { get; set; }
    public string GalleryName { get; set; }
    public byte IsSystemGallery { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<GalleryItem> GalleryItems { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You shouldn't bind your Business Objects directly to your UI. Create a proper BL and ViewModels to bind these objects.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of that, but I am merely learning MVVM as I go and please believe me, this isn't any production code yet. The problem is here how to achieve the result. Or exactly for me to understand why List<T> works as DataContext but ObservableCollection<T> does not. They both implement IEnumerable<T> and IList<T> (the latter via Collection<T>) which I thought was the requirement, so what makes them different? As @echo suggested might I be missing loading of the data? But then why .ToList() loads the data on its own?

Comment: The DbSet<T> entry *is* an IQueryable<T> and as such does not contain any data. It does implement IEnumerable<T> for the linq approach, however does only contain the query/filter information. Enumerating this IQueryable, for example via the .Load extension method or through .ToList() (into another List instance) will load the data by executing the query (see deferred execution in linq). ObservableCollection should work as a source for binding, and you should be able to create an ObservableCollection via the list. Binding the context graph to a view directly is a bad practice though.

Comment: Ok, so I'm back to re-reading chapter about collections. I think I understand now, thanks to your explanation, why this collection is empty. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to call IQueryable.Load() prior to binding to DbSet.Local:

```
myEntities = new MyEntities();
myEntities.GalleryLists.Load();
grMain.DataContext = myEntities.GalleryLists.Local;
```

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't such a function available on this object as Load() (or on .Local property as well). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Plus why does ToList() work without any prior call to Load() function (should there be one), it's a type casting function, it shouldn't be doing any data loading, or does it?

Comment: See this article from MSDN about the Load extension method, and follow the link about why you might use it when working with Local data. 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592911(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Load is an extension method, you need to import the System.Data.Entity namespace

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I missed Intellisense light bulb suggesting adding this namespace...